# Algoritmo para leitura de vários números em PHP

Tags: php, html, algoritmo

Tenho uma dúvida sobre como fazer o seguinte exercício em PHP utilizando formulários HTML:

Faça um algoritmo que leia uma sequência de números inteiros. Se o usuário digitar
um número negativo o algoritmo deverá retornar a média dos números digitados (sem
o valor negativo).

Em uma outra linguagem de programação, eu criaria um laço de repetição com a condição de parada sendo o valor lido ser um número negativo, porém não sei como fazer isso para uma requisição POST, o que foi solicitado pela professora. Se puderem me ajudar, ficaria muito grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo.
A minha sugestão é ler toda a sequência e depois dar um split na sequência.

```
$sequencia = explode(",",$_POST["sequencia"]);
$soma = 0;
foreach ($sequencia as &$valor) {
  if ( $valor > 0 )
     $soma += $valor
  else break; }
```

Espero ter ajudado